# How to set conditions on an Ansible variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I need to restrict a variable `vm_name`, in my playbook, to 15 characters, `[0-9]`, `[a-z]`, `[A-Z]`, `-_`, no special characters like `#$%*&`.
How can I achieve this?

```yaml
- name: Set Vars conditions
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    vm_name: "abcdefgh12_12-0"
  tasks:
  - name: Print vm_name
    debug: 
       msg: "{{ vm_name }}"
```

I found you can use `|int` but I didn't find an option to block special characters or how to fail the task if it doesn't meet the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the filter [`regex_findall`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/regex_findall_filter.html) to fit your condition, and accompany it with *[slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/how-slicing-in-python-works)*, to limit the length of the string.

Then, to reduce the string to the acceptable pattern, you could do:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    vm_name: "{{ (vm_name | regex_findall('[A-Za-z0-9-_]'))[:15] | join }}"
  vars:
    vm_name: )a&bc"d#efgh12_12-0(22
```

Which gives something like

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => changed=false 
  ansible_facts:
    vm_name: abcdefgh12_12-0
```

*<sup>Note: the above output was generated running the playbook with the option `-v`, which, amongst other useful information, shows the result of a `set_fact` task.</sup>*

Or, if you want to fail:

```yaml
- assert:
    ## By testing the length before and after the regex filtering
    ## and the slicing, we assert if the filtering did alter the 
    ## string length, and so, the fact that the original string
    ## did contain invalid character or was too long
    that: "(
        vm_name | regex_findall('[A-Za-z0-9-_]')
      )[:15] | join | length == vm_name | length"
  vars:
    vm_name: abcdefgh12_12-0
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) of a valid password and remove other characters

```yaml
  vm_name_regex: '[^-\w]'
  vm_name_valid: "{{ (vm_name|regex_replace(vm_name_regex, ''))[:15] }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    vm_name: ')a&bc"d#efgh12_12-0(22'
    
    vm_name_regex: '[^-\w]'
    vm_name_valid: "{{ (vm_name|regex_replace(vm_name_regex, ''))[:15] }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: vm_name_valid
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  vm_name_valid: abcdefgh12_12-0

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```